# Connected to MySQL database but cannot print the data

Tags: mysql, php

I connected successfully to my database and the I tried to print my data but I can only see the "Connected succesfully" line in the browser. Here is my code:

```
<?php 

$db=@mysqli_connect("host","root","pass");
if (!db) { die('Cannot connect with the database.');}

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

$sql = "SELECT username FROM students";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "username: " . $row["username"].  "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();



?>
```

Comment: This appears to be a programming issue - if you've connected to the database, then it's certainly not a dba issue.

Comment: I'm running this on a CentOS server. The php version is 5.3.3 and I am really confused from all this stuff I read about the mysql connection changes between the different php versions.

Comment: Version of MySQL? Have you tried running the raw SQL code against the database using the MySQL client? Although, `SELECT STUDENTNAME FROM students` is hardly rocket science - does the table exist? Does it have any records?

Comment: Version 5.1.73. Its working fine if i run this with the mysql client, it shows my records. The weird thing that i have done this exactly on localhost and it worked but on this Centos server its dead after the connection

Comment: Why can't you upgrade - 5.1 is almost as old as I am... not quite but you know what I mean. Maybe an older driver if you can't upgrade.

Comment: Updated to 5.5 and still nothing.

Comment: I even put an echo "blabla" under the query and it doesn't show that either.

Comment: Is it showing "0 results"?

Comment: The only thing that is printed is "Connected successfully" only this.

Comment: Puzzled - I think that you'll have to try on StackOverflow. Is the host your dev machine? Are you **sure** that your MySQL client and your PHP programme are pointed at the same system? If that doesn't work, I'm all out of ideas. It's not as if the code is complex - but I don't know PHP.

Comment: No, the host is just a server provided from a goverment program for students.The mysql and the php are pointed at this host. I will the stackoverflow guys too.

Comment: Lemme know the result @Vérace here and I'll get the message.

Comment: @Vérace So after a few modification it didnt work but finally i found the problem. SELinux was blocking remote connections from PHP scripts executed by Apache web server. I had to type setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect=1 in the terminal and it did the trick. Thank you for your time btw.

Comment: Check for errors after each call.  That may give you the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely have to check your query execution response, as clearly *suggested* by the [mysqli::query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php), by adding the following code fragment just after the query call.

```
if (!$result) {
    printf("Error: [%s] %s<br/>", $conn->errno, $conn->error);
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: i tried the above too but it seems nothing yet i can't find any error or error message